# Why is my Java Merge-Sort faster than my C++ implementation?

Tags: java, c++, runtime, mergesort

I implemented the Merge Sort in Java and in C++ and I tried to implement them as similar as possible. Both algorithms work, I tested them many times. The problem is that my Java-Implementation is a lot faster than my C++-Implementation and I am wondering why. I can't believe that Java would be faster so I guess I made a mistake in one of the implementations. In order to measure the runtime I created a class "Person" which has two String-Attributes (forename, lastname). In C++ I used `std::vector<Person*>` and in Java I used `ArrayList<Person>`. Additionally I overloaded the `operator<` in C++ to compare two Persons (compare the lastname, if equal compare the firstname). In Java I implemented the interface `Comparable<Person>` to compare two Persons.

*Can you find a mistake in my code or a reason why Java would be faster or C++ would be slower? Any help would be appreciated.*

**My Java Code:**

```
public void mergeSort(List<T> list) {
    if (list.size() <= 1) {
        return;
    }

    int subLength = (int) (list.size() / 2);
    List<T> first = new ArrayList<T>(list.subList(0, subLength));
    List<T> second = new ArrayList<T>(list.subList(subLength, list.size()));


    mergeSort(first);
    mergeSort(second);

    merge(first, second, list);
    return;
}

private void merge(List<T> first, List<T> second, List<T> result) {
    int firstPos = 0, secondPos = 0, resultPos = 0;

    while (firstPos < first.size() && secondPos < second.size()) {
        if (first.get(firstPos).compareTo(second.get(secondPos)) < 0) {
            result.set(resultPos, first.get(firstPos));
            firstPos++;
        } else {
            result.set(resultPos, second.get(secondPos));
            secondPos++;
        }
        resultPos++;
    }

    for (int i = firstPos; i < first.size(); i++) {
        result.set(resultPos, first.get(i));
        resultPos++;
    }
    for (int i = secondPos; i < second.size(); i++) {
        result.set(resultPos, second.get(i));
        resultPos++; 
    }
}
```

**My C++ Code:**

Note: I used two template-methods to make the mergesort usable with both `Person` and `Person*`.

```
template<typename T>
    T * ptr(T & obj) { return &obj; } 

    template<typename T>
    T * ptr(T * obj) { return obj; }


void mergeSort(std::vector<T> &list) {
        if (list.size() <= 1) {
            return;
        }

        int subLength = (int)(list.size() / 2);
        std::vector<T> first(list.begin(), list.begin() + subLength);
        std::vector<T> second(list.begin() + subLength, list.end());

        mergeSort(first);
        mergeSort(second);

        merge(first, second, list);

    }
void merge(const std::vector<T> &first, const std::vector<T> &second, std::vector<T> &result) {
        int firstPos = 0, secondPos = 0, resultPos = 0;
        while (firstPos < first.size() && secondPos < second.size()) {
            if (*ptr(first[firstPos]) < *ptr(second[secondPos])) {
                result[resultPos] = first[firstPos];
                firstPos++;
            }
            else {
                result[resultPos] = second[secondPos];
                secondPos++;
            }
            resultPos++;
        }

        for (int i = firstPos; i < first.size(); i++) {
            result[resultPos] = first[i];
            resultPos++;
        }
        for (int i = secondPos; i < second.size(); i++) {
            result[resultPos] = second[i];
            resultPos++;
        }
    }
```

**Edit1 and 2:**

My setup-configuration:

I used one million, 10 millionen and 20 millionen persons to test the implementations. I doesn't really matter with how many Persons I test it with, Java is always faster.

And I test it the following way: I create persons and initialize my `MergeSort`-class. Then I start the measurement and I call my `mergeSort`-method. When the sorting is finished I stop the measurement. (Deleting is happening after the time measurement). For the time measurement in Java I use `System.nanoTime()` and in C++ I use `chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point`

Of course I compiled C++ in "Release"-Mode (Optimization: O2, faster code preferred).

My Test-PC:

- Intel i5 2500
- 8GB DDR3 RAM
- Windows 10 Education

**Edit3:**

There is one thing I forgot to mention. I implemented the algorithm in a generic way in order to use simple data-types as well as objects. When I use `std::vector<int>` and `ArrayList<Integer>` in Java then my C++ implementation is a lot faster. My first attempt was to use `std::vector<Person>` but it was even slower. So my guess was that it made deep copies instead of shallow ones and that's why I switched to `Person*` because I thought that when copying is happening only the pointers will be copied.

Comment: Whats the setup of your performance tests? Whats your sample size? How is the time measured?

Comment: This probably belongs on code review.

Comment: Ok I am sorry. Should I delete the question?

Comment: `ArrayList` and `vector` are not the best containers to use in this algorithm.

Comment: What container would you suggest then?

Comment: A list, in C++ it's `std::list`

Comment: Ok, maybe you are right. Nevertheless I think that these implementations are pretty similar in terms of data structures etc. Do you find any other mistake besides using the wrong container?

Comment: IMHO `vector` is the best container to use here (looking at the code!) `std::list` only adds overhead. (BTW `*ptr(...)` can be safely omitted)

Comment: I use `*ptr(...)` to make my Merge-Sort usable with both `Person` and `Person*`.

Comment: @Elijan9 a `std::vector` has to be expensively resized sometimes.

Comment: @killexe If you're trying to compare identical code getting rid of your `ptr` functions should be done in short order.

Comment: I would also suggest to check the optimization flags - quite possible that C++ program is compiled with -O0, then I'd suggest to try -O2.

Comment: @alain only in case you get out of the preallocated space. But in this case you can see the OP is not adding new elements to vectors and in most cases you can actually predict the total number of entries, so that you can create a vector of needed length

Comment: @Chaosit I did that. _Of course I compiled C++ in "Release"-Mode (Optimization: O2, faster code preferred)._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** - The Java version does alot less array copying.

The [ArrayList constructor (see line 167)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) of `ArrayList` when passed a `Collection` uses `Collection.toArray()` and optionally `Arrays.copyOf` if required. <s>In the case of an `ArrayList` there is no need to take a copy - `toArray()` returns a reference to the underlying array</s>.

Note also that the `if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)` will cause the array not to be copied again.

The Java `List.subList` on `ArrayList` objects does not copy any of the underlying array, it just returns an `ArrayList` backed by the original but limited to the elements required.

As a result - in may cases the whole mechanism uses sub-lists that actually just refer to the original array - no copying is required.

Not too familiar with C++ but I suspect there is a lot of array copying and allocation going on which just doesn't need to be done by Java.

ADDED - As @ThomasKläger rightly pointed out, `ArrayList.toArray` actually does return a defensive copy of the array - so I was wrong above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to figure out if there is really that much allocation and copying done. I will mark this answer as "accepted" when I tried it out.

Comment: There indeed is alot of copying in C++ version. In `mergeSort()` line `std::vector<T> first(list.begin(), list.begin() + subLength);` and the next one call vector range constructor, which `Constructs a container with as many elements as the range [first,last), with each element emplace-constructed from its corresponding element in that range, in the same order.`. In other words this increases running time by nlogn copy operations.

Comment: "_`toArray()` returns a refernce to the underlying array_" - no, it does not, it creates a copy of the underlying array (see your referenced source, line 361). This is also clearly stated in the JavaDoc of `ArrayList.toArray()`: **In other words, this method must allocate
 a new array**

Comment: When I call `std::vector<T> first(list.begin(), list.begin() + subLength);` wouldn't there just the pointers to the `Person`s be copied?

Comment: @ThomasKläger - Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Thanks again for this answer! I also implemented the Merge-Sort in C# (it was also slower than Java) therefore I looked up the implementation of `List<T>.GetRange`-Method and it uses `Array.Copy` to copy the elements. That's why I think the results are plausible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One of the 1<sup>st</sup> things I see is in your statement:

> Deleting is happening after the time measurement

You're speaking of deleting of the `Person` objects, you're obviously not speaking of the containers, such as `first` and `second` which C++ is creating and cleaning on the stack:

```
std::vector<T> first(list.begin(), list.begin() + subLength);
std::vector<T> second(list.begin() + subLength, list.end());
```

while Java is creating them on the heap and not cleaning them up till it gets around to it (so after you stop timing):

```
List<T> first = new ArrayList<T>(list.subList(0, subLength));
List<T> second = new ArrayList<T>(list.subList(subLength, list.size()));
```

So you're timing C++ with container cleanup and Java without.

---

I have to ask here, what's the point of writing your own merge sort? The best Java and C++ code would use the sorting algorithms already provided by the language. If you're looking to time something at least time the optimized algorithms.

Also I wouldn't put a lot of work into time comparisons. C++ *will* be faster, it will generally be more work to write as well. If speed is important enough to you to bother with timing you probably want to be using C++. If development time is king then you'll want to be using Java.

Comment: You are right and I won't use these algorithms in _real_ applications because I know that the algorithms provided by the languages themselves will be faster than mine obviously. My goal was to find out the speed difference in a _pratical use_ so I decided to implement an algorithm by myself to do so. Of course I cannot guarantee that the measurement is 100% fair but I try to make it as fair as possible. Do you think that the reason for the time difference is that C++ is deleting the `std::vector` containers at the end of the method?

Comment: @killexe Obviously there could be more problems in the code I can't see. The `ptr` function is also something extra in the C++ code, but the compiler should simplify that. But yeah, in the code that you've presented that is the significant difference that I see. Either way, I appreciate that you've taken the time to use reference arguments in the C++ code and all that. It's very easy on the eyes :)